# do i have to regenerate wsdl after changing the webservice method

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I am trying to learn webservices,

I have created a webservice and client after watching tutorials and my client is getting the input from webmethod successfully.

What i did is, i just created a test webservice method to retun a hardcoded string to client.

But when i change the hardcoded value to something new and run the client, it is not getting the updated value, it is still displaying the old value.

Do i have to regenerate client or any other step needed to get the updated weservice call ...???

please guide me ...

Comment: Please guide us - what language, framework,ide, etc?  But the answer, should be, no.  You should not have to do anything with the wsdl file.

Comment: Hi,
I have written in java and the ide im using is Eclipse and server is Glassfish 4.0

The method i used for testing at first returned just a string "Im working".

After that i just changed the string to "I have changed".  But still in the client the output im getting is "Im working".

Comment: Did you try doing a clean and build?

Comment: Thanks OldProgrammer !!!!
It worked, im new to Java , So i dont know all the basic process..
Thanks Again :)